# Jupyter notebook can not find installed module

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When started, Jupyter notebook encounters a problem with module import

```
import findspark
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ff073c74b5db> in <module>
----> 1 import findspark

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'findspark'
```

Conda list shows that module is here

```
filelock                  3.0.8                    py37_0  
findspark                 1.3.0                      py_1    conda-forge
flask                     1.0.2                    py37_1
```

Python version

```
(myenv) mm@mm-HP-EliteBook-8560p:~$ python -V
Python 3.6.8
```

It seems that my installation is not clean.
Three Python lines from `.bash_profile`

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

Why do I get import error?

Comment: This can happen for many reasons. Most likely you are thinking you are starting the notebook with a specific python version, but you are actually starting it with another instance of python.
It can be something in your `.bashrc` or something like this. Maybe try again by isolating clearly the python instance.

Comment: Ok,which env variable should I search for?

Comment: What is your machine (ubuntu, centos, windows)? and note that you can run multiple python kernels in jupyter, so it may be a matter of running the wrong one? (you can see it in the top right corner)

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04,have you seen my edit?

Comment: Jupyter shows Python3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest a slightly different route.

1. Download spark on your local. Let's say you've unzipped in `/Users/me/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7` location.
2. Assuming you're on mac, update your `~/.bash_profile` to contain these entries:

   ```
   export SPARK_HOME=/Users/me/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7
   export PYTHONPATH=${SPARK_HOME}/python:$PYTHONPATH
   export PYTHONPATH=${SPARK_HOME}/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH

   export PYSPARK_PYTHON=<path to your python location>
   export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
   export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook

   PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
   ```
3. Execute a `source ~/.bash_profile`.
4. From your bash shell, just run `pyspark` and it'll open the jupyter notebook. Now your notebook will be tied to this spark installation.

If you're using linux, I think the only change is in the syntax for appending stuffs to path, and instead of changing `bash_profile` you probably need to change `bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct [virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv).

Create a fresh virtualenv for your work (eg. using 3.7.4 as an example here. Use a version you have installed):

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.7.4 myenv
```

You can see which python versions you have installed with:

```
pyenv versions
```

And which versions are available for installation with:

```
pyenv install -l
```

You can either activate the virtualenv shell with:

```
pyenv shell myenv
```

With the virtualenv active, you should see the virtualenv name before your prompt. Something like "(myenv)~$: "

Now install all the python packages as you normally would. Make sure you are in the right virutalenv before you run your packages. You can also set the PYENV_VERSION environment variable to specify the virtualenv to use. Something like:

```
PYENV_VERSION=myenv python -m pip install findspark
```

Then

```
PYENV_VERSION=myenv python -m pip show findspark
```

Should give you something like:

```
Name: findspark
Version: 1.3.0
Summary: Find pyspark to make it importable.
Home-page: https://github.com/minrk/findspark
Author: Min RK
Author-email: benjaminrk@gmail.com
License: BSD (3-clause)
Location: /home/tzhuang/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```